# How to programmatically find a "Y" pose such that it is the inverse of another "X" pose in relation to the T-pose?

Tags: python, scripting, armature, bones, transforms

That is, if I "Apply" the armature modifier of the "Y" pose onto the mesh then if I now link that mesh to the armature of the "X" pose the mesh should look like the original mesh in T-pose.
The following code should find the "Y" pose:

```
import bpy

# Get armatures
armature_x = bpy.data.objects['armatureX'] 
armature_t = bpy.data.objects['armatureT'] 
armature_y = armature_t.copy()
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(armature_y)

# Get poses
pose_x = armature_x.pose
pose_t = armature_t.pose
pose_y = armature_y.pose

# Iterate through bones
for bone_x in pose_x.bones:
    bone_t = pose_t.bones[bone_x.name]
    bone_y = pose_y.bones[bone_x.name]
  
    bone_x.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    bone_t.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    bone_y.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    
    bone_y.location += bone_t.location - bone_x.location
    bone_y.rotation_euler[0] += bone_t.rotation_euler[0] - bone_x.rotation_euler[0]
    bone_y.rotation_euler[1] += bone_t.rotation_euler[1] - bone_x.rotation_euler[1]
    bone_y.rotation_euler[2] += bone_t.rotation_euler[2] - bone_x.rotation_euler[2]
    bone_y.scale[0] *= bone_t.scale[0]/bone_x.scale[0]
    bone_y.scale[1] *= bone_t.scale[1]/bone_x.scale[1]
    bone_y.scale[2] *= bone_t.scale[2]/bone_x.scale[2]
```

However when I "Apply" the armature modifier (in "Y" pose) onto the mesh and then add an armature modifier linked to the "X" pose, this mesh doesn't appear to be in the T-pose, it gets close but is deformed. What is really going on? Why doesn't this mesh look like the original mesh in T-pose?